# SQL to calculate multilevel discount

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My Schema :

```
Table: Product
ItemID      Price      Disc1      Disc2      Disc3
001         1000       1          2          3
002         500        10         0          0
003         500        10         2          8

Table: Sales
ItemID      Price      Qty      Disc1      Disc2      Disc3      SubTotal
001         1000       1        1          2          3          941.09
```

I want to have a better way to calculate multilevel discount like this :

```
Price       Disc1       Disc2       Disc3
1000        1           2           3
500         10          0           0
500         10          2           8
```

to become :

```
Price       Disc1       Disc2       Disc3     NetPrice
1000        1           2           3         941.09
500         10          0           0         450
500         10          2           8         405.72
```

This discount is not sum of all discount

For item #1:

NOT Price * (1+2+3)

but like this:
((Price - (Price*(1/100))) - ((Price - (Price*(1/100))) * (2/100))) - (((Price - (Price*(1/100))) - ((Price - (Price*(1/100))) * (2/100))) * (3/100))

Explanation Item 0001:

Step 1: 1000 - (1/100)   //result : 990

Step 2: 990 - (2/100)   //result : 970.2

Step 2: 970.2 - (3/100)   //result : 941.09 -> this is what i need

Basically just like a common store discount, and i can calculate this way :

```
Select ((Price - (Price*(1/100))) - ((Price - (Price*(1/100))) * (2/100))) - (((Price - (Price*(1/100))) - ((Price - (Price*(1/100))) * (2/100))) * (3/100)) From [MyTable]
```

Is there any better way to calculate this? because some of my cust can have more than 4 discounts.

any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What's your table schema?

Comment: @Zoff....i dont put my schema cos i dont think it has anything to do with the query...does it?

Comment: Yes it does. SQL is a language to manipulate table so we need to know the shape of the table we are manipulating. I don't know if your table has `Disc1`, `Disc2`, ... `DiscN` columns or whatever else it is.

Comment: how many Disc columns are there?

Comment: I think the first row should be 941.09, not 941.04.

Comment: Ok...i will put the schema then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is simpler:

```
select Price * (1 - 1.0 / 100) * (1 - 2.0 / 100) * (1 - 3.0 / 100)
```

which in terms of your data is:

```
select Price * (1 - disc1 / 100) * (1 - disc2 / 100) * (1 - disc3 / 100)
```

SQL Fiddle doesn't seem to be working, but you can run this code:

I think this is simpler:

```
select Price * (1 - 1.0 / 100) * (1 - 2.0 / 100) * (1 - 3.0 / 100)
```

which in terms of your data is:

```
select Price * (1 - disc1 / 100) * (1 - disc2 / 100) * (1 - disc3 / 100)
```

SQL Fiddle doesn't seem to be working, but you can run this code:

```
with t as (
      select 1 as id, 1000 as price, 1.0 as disc1, 2.0 as disc2, 3.0 as disc3 union all
      select 2, 500, 10, 0, 0 union all
      select 3, 500, 10, 2, 8
     )
select id, price * (1 - disc1/100) * (1 - disc2/100) * (1-disc3/100)
from t;
```

Comment: @Viandry . . . When I calculate the values using your original data, the only difference is the first one, which you have as 941.04.  I think this is a typo; the value I get is 941.094.

Comment: yup...its typo...it should 941.094

Comment: (and that's exactly the problem with posts that depend on SQLfiddle)